# Issues with flask's render_template() and javascript export

Tags: javascript, python, flask

**Preface:**

I'm following several tutorials to cobble a project together, and I feel as though my starting point is a little below sea level.

**Background:**

I'm trying to create a chess related project to put on a website. I followed [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app) about building a python project on Google's App Engine and creating a web service for it. I've gone through the tutorial but omitted the Firebase section.

From that baseline, I've tacked on [chessboard.js](https://chessboardjs.com/), and I was able to get that working - the pieces and the board show up at least.

Next, I tried incorporating [chess.js](https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js/blob/master/README.md), but I'm running into an unexpected issue (i.e. unexpected to me). The chessboard.js website actually has integration examples, and I've tried to follow those, but I believe the App Engine tutorial is actually preventing the chess.js code from functioning.

**My Thoughts on the Problem:**

Because I'm just editing the index.html file from the App Engine tutorial and trying to get it to work, I believe Flask's render_template() function which gets fed the index.html file is freaking out when it sees the "export" statements in the chess.js code.

The chessboard.js seems to work just fine by itself, but when I "inspect" the website that gets generated and go to "console" (using Google Chrome). I see an "unexpected_token" error result from chess.js in line 252, which is where the "export" statements begin.

**The Request:**

Personally, I have next to no clue if what I've deduced is right or not. I have enough understanding of what I'm envisioning to get this far but not enough to understand alternatives or best practices (i.e. beyond stitching together tutorials and examples). If someone could shed some light on how to overcome the "export" token error issue I'm getting from chess.js when the index.html file is passed to Flask's render_template() function, that would be greatly appreciated!

I think the crucial issue is that python and javascript both use "export"s and that isn't getting resolved well.

Thank you very much in advance!

Edit: Added Code

**Summary of index.html:**

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/chess.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='chessboard-1.0.0.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center" id="myBoard" style="width: 600px"></div>

    <script>
        var board = null
        var game = new Chess()

        function makeRandomMove () {
            var possibleMoves = game.moves()

            // exit if the game is over
            if (game.game_over()) return

            var randomIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleMoves.length)
            game.move(possibleMoves[randomIdx])
            board.position(game.fen())

            window.setTimeout(makeRandomMove, 500)
        }

        board = Chessboard('myBoard', 'start')

        window.setTimeout(makeRandomMove, 500)
    </script>
</body>
```

In a nutshell, the code above holds the important elements of the index.html file. I'm using jquery, chess.js, and chessboard.js. Using filepaths and url_for() both seem to work, so I believe I was able to rule that out as being an issue. Additionally, the code above should just be the [random vs. random example](https://chessboardjs.com/examples#5002) from the integrations section of the chessboard.js website.

**Portion of main.py:**

```
import datetime

from flask import Flask, render_template
from google.cloud import datastore

app = Flask(__name__)

datastore_client = datastore.Client()

@app.route('/')
def root():
    # Store the current access time in Datastore.
    store_time(datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc))

    # Fetch the most recent 10 access times from Datastore.
    times = fetch_times(10)

    return render_template('index.html', times=times)
```

That's a portion of the main.py file that's receiving the index.html file. This file is largely unchanged compared to what's being provided by the Google App Engine tutorial mentioned previously.

Comment: Please, attache the codes.

Comment: @user17517503 Thank you for the suggestion! I've added portions of my code. If you need any more information, I'll do my best to accommodate the request!

Comment: You need to use url_for in the link for chess.js in exactly the same way you have for chessboard.js

Comment: @EAW Actually, my very first implementation of this code relied on the url_for() to retrieve chess.js. The issue I ran into with that - and subsequently why I opted to just try the direct static folder path thing - was an issue stemming from my version of the chess.js code in line 252. For one reason or another, there were export statements in the code that weren't playing well with Flask's render_template() parser. I was able to use a URL instead that managed to do just fine. However, it's also a chess.js version without those same export statements.